# Need javascript help to click button on hover for map tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this map that I have created using a wp plugin, where when you click on the icons, you get a tooltip popup over an image. https://kneedeepinit.com/vieques-beaches/

I would like it if someone could hover over each icon and have it popup, but with the built in options, if you hover, then try to move your mouse onto the tooltip, it disappears because the tooltip was tied to the hover of the icon.

My thought is someone could help me with some javascript to click the icons on hover?

Comment: Betcha could google hover click javascript and it'd give you solutions.

Comment: It did, and I tried somethings. As you can see below, I was close, but wrong. Ercan got it right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add jquery and this code. basically, this code triggers `click` event.

```
$('.uabb-icon-wrap').on('mouseenter', function(){
     $(this).trigger('click')
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I was so close!
 `$(“.uabb-hotspot-item").hover(function() {
        $(“.uabb-hotspot-item").click();
 `});